# Finding probabilities for non-standard normal distribution

Tags: r, probability, distribution

I have a non-standard normal distribution with x~N(2,9). 2 is mean and 9 is standard deviation. I want to solve the below probabilities:

```
a) P(x<-0.3)  b) P(x=1)   c) P(x>5)  d) P(|x-2|<3)
```

I have written the below codes for them:

```
for a) pnorm(-0.3,2,9)
for c) 1-pnorm(5,2,9)
for d) pnorm(5,2,9)-pnorm(-1,2,9)
```

I don't know how to solve and code case b) which is P(x=1).
Also, I want to find ***quantile 0.9*** for this distribution. But I don't know how to code it in R for such non-standard normal distribution.

Comment: (b) might be a trick question.  The *probability* of a point value (`x=1`) for a continuous distribution is 0.  Are you looking for the probability *density* (`?dnorm`); for quantiles, try `?qnorm`.

Comment: For the 0.9 quantile, you need to use the inverse CDF.  For all distributions, P{a < X <= b} = F(b) - F(a), but for continuous distributions you can replace the "<" on the left with "<=", which should give you a big hint for part (b).

Comment: @BenBolker, Thank you for your comment. Is there a command in R that using it we receive 0 in output as the answer of P(x=1)?

Comment: @pjs. Thank you for your answer. What is the inverse CDF? and how can we use it for finding 0.9 quantile?

Comment: @vahid That's what [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Normal) is for.  Everything you need is on that page, other than the hint I gave for (b).

Comment: @vahid no (unless you follow @pjs's hint and use a *difference* of `pnorm()` values ...).  It might be useful to give us  more context.  Technically `P(x=1)` is zero for any Normal distribution, but it's possible that the person asking the question is actually interested in the probability density, *or* the probability that `0.5<x<1.5`, or something else.